I'm trying to write an assembly language program that prints my name using a loop, but I can't figure out the issue or if I am doing it wrong on MASM?
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    name db 'YourName', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
    count db 5

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov cx,5 count  ; Set loop counter to 5

print_name:
    
    mov ah, 9    ; DOS function to print string
    lea dx, name
    int 21h        ; Call DOS interrupt

    loop print_name ; Loop until CX is 0

    mov ah, 4Ch    ; DOS function to terminate program
    int 21h        ; Call DOS interrupt
main endp
end main

I have tried moving around the commands and altered the data a bit but instead of activating, I got 4 errors and a warning. ie: A4011, A2008, A2206, A2004 and the normal error: MSB3721. I expected it to print "YourName" 5 times

When asking a question on Stack Overflow, you should always quote complete error messages, not just error codes. For example, "warning A4011: multiple .MODEL directives found : .MODEL ignored". The cause of this warning in your case is including Irvine32.inc, which in turn includes another INC-file where a .MODEL already exists. So, perhaps don't specify your own model or, alternatively, don't include Irvine32.inc at all?
